# Azure DevOPS PowerShell task output and input parameters

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a Task Group with a PowerShell task. This task returns variables as outputs.
In my pipeline I have two tasks after this Task Group task:

- One that is an ARM deployment task: I'm able to retrieve the content of the output variables from the PowerShell (with the "$(variablename)" syntax)
- One that is another Task Group with a PowerShell task in it. When I pass the "$(variableName)" token as an input parameter for this task, it is not interpreted. In the PowerShell script I received the string "$(variableName)", and not the value of the variable itself...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `##vso` syntax to set the output variable in the first task group.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var1;isOutput=true;]test"
```

[image]

In the subsequent tasks or task group, get the variable in the form of `task name + ordinal combination`. e.g. **`$(Powershell1.VariableName)`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can refer to this [ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6983) with similar issue .

Comment: What do you do if the task name has spaces or dots?